# Allow a python application to run if the user's password is wrong

Tags: login, password, authentication

Is it possible to let a python program execute only if a wrong password is given at the login screen of my raspberry pi?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I'm afraid your question is very unclear. What password? Why would the program require it? How is the password provided? When is it given? Do you mean at login?  Who checks it? What is the python script supposed to do? Do you mean you want to launch an application _only_ if a wrong password is given? Would this be via `sudo`? Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Comment: You might try looking into using `fail2ban` to do something like this via [actions](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Actions).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [libpam-script](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libpam-script). It allows you to execute scripts during authorization, password changes and sessions.

To meet your need, you can build a PAM configuration (in `/etc/pam.d/<whatever>`) that arranges for this module to execute right before `pam_deny` only if the normal sequence of modules denies the login.